# Choose distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have 2 processes, P1 and P2. P1 has outcome O with probability 20% and P2 has outcome O with probability 30%. I am running a simulation and at each step would like to choose either P1 or P2 so that the probability of outcome O is 22%. How do I choose P1 or P2?

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: I have no relevant knowledge expect a probability class 30 years ago in college. I am writing a detection software which can detect at levels L1 and L2. At L2 we detect everything but we get a lot of false positives. At level L1 we do not have false positives but we have some false negatives. We would like to mostly detect at L1 since we can't afford to handle all the false positives but some times would like to switch to L2 to keep the adversary on the edge. We figured a good way to do that is to have a target goal of detections. Would like to understand the mathematics of this.

Comment: Ah, ok. You might want to edit some of the above info into your question to help give more context to your problem. I imagine people will be more willing to help you if you do.